# RNCryptor: Which settings to change to improve performance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, rncryptor

I have a lot of short strings to decrypt in my app and **decryption speed** is critical.

Currently I am experimenting with `RNCryptor` but find its default settings a bit slow for my use case. Otherwise it is an awesome framework :-)

**Encryption** will be done only once and hence its performance is not important.

I am fine giving up protection for speed as I just want to have a very basic encryption in place.

Which `RNCryptor` settings would you recommend using to encrypt and decrypt in order to accomplish the fastest decryption performance? A short code sample would be great!

Again, I am fine with very basic encryption protection for the current use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lion's share of time in RNCryptor are in the calls to PBKDF2. It iterates 20,000 times (10,000 for each key). While it may get a little faster in upcoming versions of RNCryptor, password-based encryption will always be slow. This is a security feature; it's slow on purpose. It's designed to be slow in a way that frustrates attackers while having acceptable impact on the most common use cases.

You can dramatically improve performance by using the key-based, rather than password-based, methods. The key-based methods have no injected slowdowns. This would be my recommended approach if possible. Generate two random 256-bits keys rather than using a password.

You can potentially set the number of PBKDF2 iterations to a smaller number (and that's necessary when dealing with JavaScript for instance), but the faster you make key generation, the worse your security is going to be.

There are a number of ways to modify the format to improve performance for your use case, but it's very easy to mess it up and significantly hurt security. As @Zaph notes, I would either do a lot of study or engage an expert before modifying any security framework.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't much you can do, `RNCryptor` is not slow.

AES128 will be a little faster than AES256 -- or not depending on the platform.

There is a large cost in the setup so that is a place to possibly make things faster. One possibility is combining the strings.

If you could make all the strings a multiple of block size you could use one setup, ECB mode and the partial CCryptor functions. Note, ECB mode will **degrade security** especially on short strings. Setup with `CCCryptorCreate()`and decrypt with the short padded strings with `CCCryptorUpdate()`.

Another thing to consider is [TinyCrypt](http://tinycrypt.sourceforge.net). "The first point of TinyCrypt is to both compress and encrypt your file VERY quickly." I rarely suggest other than AES and using non-mainstream cyphers is **dodgy at best**--but you stated you were willing to tradeoff security for speed.

Comment: I will look definitively look into `TinyCrypt`. Any idea on how to improve the performance of setting up `RNCryptor`? I just use it in one line of code: `NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:encryptedData withPassword:password error:&decryptionError];`.

Comment: Most encryption methods have to create a lot of state on startup so that is the only real hope for speed. Most of the chip sets have some form of encryption support. I suspect that Rob will provide some help. Best advice, get a crypto domain expert to write your encryption code or at least review it--if you care about the security.

Comment: Can you recommend an crypto expert (preferable with iOS and Core Data experience)?

Comment: [Rob Napier](http://robnapier.net) and [Graham Lee](http://blog.securemacprogramming.com) come to mind immediately. The people I have used for review are in the financial industry.